# Using a Custom Directive in an Angular 2 NgBootstrap Modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular app (4.3.3) using NgBootstrap (1.0.0-alpha.30, with Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6)

I'm using ngBootstrap to display a couple of modal windows and the code (mostly) works as expected.

I also have a custom directive in the application.

When I apply the directive to HTML within the app then the directive is rendered. However, if I try and use the same directive in the HTML for the modal dialog it doesn't work, the modal does not recognise the attribute I add as an Angular directive.

I think I'm missing something fundamental here - do i need to tell ngBootstrap something to recognise the directive?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PYbiyN89NkAHAkF0HD9t?p=preview - could you try to modify this plunker to illustrate the issue?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource Thanks for doing that, it pointed me in the right direction. I had declared the component but not exported it from the module. I had a feeling it was something fundamental that I was missing